# Reveal All list items - using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a simple piece of code to hide then display list items.

Currently, I have it working so it reveals more each time I click `Load more`. It loads it in batches of 5, however, I'd like to reveal all the list items in the unordered list when I click `Load more`.

How do I achieve this with my current code?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jtg7n4wj/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
         $('#showLess').show();
        if(x == size_li){
            $('#loadMore').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
        $('#loadMore').show();
         $('#showLess').show();
        if(x == 3){
            $('#showLess').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#myList li{ display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <li>Thirteen</li>
    <li>Fourteen</li>
    <li>Fifteen</li>
    <li>Sixteen</li>
    <li>Seventeen</li>
    <li>Eighteen</li>
    <li>Nineteen</li>
    <li>Twenty one</li>
    <li>Twenty two</li>
    <li>Twenty three</li>
    <li>Twenty four</li>
    <li>Twenty five</li>
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to just show all items on click? $('#myList li').show();

Comment: @Gerfried That's a very good point. I will try this shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
   size_li = $("#myList li").size();
  x = 3;
  $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
  $('#loadMore').click(function() {
    $('#myList li,#showLess').show();
    $('#loadMore').hide();
  });
  $('#showLess').click(function() {
    $('#myList li:gt(' + x + '),#showLess').hide();
    $('#loadMore').show();
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5y002xzc/

Comment: @michaelmcgurk yes

Comment: Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/jtg7n4wj/2/
Slight tweak. See when I click `Load more` then `Show Less`, it shows no results :-(

Comment: Fantastic work, @madalin! Thank you. Answer accepted shortly :-)

Answer (score 1):

Updated code

You can use [gt](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and [lt](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) to defined limits of li for show and hide

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        $('#loadMore').hide();
        $('#showLess').show();
        $('#myList li:gt(3)').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
       $('#loadMore').show();
       $('#showLess').hide();
       $('#myList li:gt(3)').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
#myList li{ display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <li>Thirteen</li>
    <li>Fourteen</li>
    <li>Fifteen</li>
    <li>Sixteen</li>
    <li>Seventeen</li>
    <li>Eighteen</li>
    <li>Nineteen</li>
    <li>Twenty one</li>
    <li>Twenty two</li>
    <li>Twenty three</li>
    <li>Twenty four</li>
    <li>Twenty five</li>
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```