# Reveal list items using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I require a list to open and reveal more items, the code I am using is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        $('#loadMore').hide();
        $('#showLess').show();
        $('#myList li:gt(3)').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
       $('#loadMore').show();
       $('#showLess').hide();
       $('#myList li:gt(3)').hide();
    });
});
```

Which works fine for one list, how do I create code for 4 lists, do I need to create 4 functions?

As you can tell I am very much beginner with javascript.

This is the original post I got the idea and code from

[Reveal All list items - using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615637/reveal-all-list-items-using-jquery/58202275?noredirect=1#comment102782535_58202275)

```
myList li{ display:none;}
#loadMore {
    color:grey;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:grey;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}

#loadMore, #showLess {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```
  <ul id="myList" class="product-list">
       <li>1</li>
       <li>2</li>
       <li>3</li>
       <li>4</li>
       <li>5</li>
       <li>6</li>
       <li>7</li>
       <li>8</li>  
  </ul>

        <div id="loadMore">Show More</div>
        <div id="showLess">Show Less</div>
```

Comment: no need to have 4 functions, you can call the same function on click and pass the listId to it (where the click happened), Now find out that list since you know the ID and show the details. In this case, you need to have different IDs to distinguish, which loadMore was clicked

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I was thinking down this route, but I don't know how it should be written. Do I need to change the #myList and create 4 ID's within that function?

Answer (score 0):

You can also not use id at all. You can use class name only. If you use class name only than code will looks like something,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
size_li = $("#myList li").size();
x=3;
$.each($('.product-list'),function(i,e) { $(e).find('li:gt(2)').hide(); });
$('#loadMore').click(function () {
    $('#loadMore').hide();
    $('#showLess').show();
    $.each($('.product-list'),function(i,e) { $(e).find('li:gt(2)').show(); });
});
$('#showLess').click(function () {
   $('#loadMore').show();
   $('#showLess').hide();
   $.each($('.product-list'),function(i,e) { $(e).find('li:gt(2)').hide(); });
});});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kjxr95hL/2/

If class name is not an option then you need to use ids. In that case you can create a common method and pass in element on it.